# Defining readProperties variable globally

Tags: jenkins

I'm writing jenkins pipeline script and using readProperties resource to get the variables from property files. But that key value is used only under exiting stage. If I have to use that key value variable in another stage it showing null. Can you anyone guide me how to define these variable globally so that I can use it in any pipeline stages

```
stage('Reading Property file for database changes') {
            steps {
            node ('master'){
                script {
                  def props = readProperties file:'/home/jenkins/details.property'
                  def var1= props['var1']
                  echo "var1=${var1}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the following does not work, update your jenkins server and plugins

```
def props

stage('Reading Property file for database changes') {
            steps {
            node ('master'){
                script {
                  props = readProperties file:'/home/jenkins/details.property'
                  def var1= props['var1']
                  echo "var1=${var1}"
```